# :dependency => :destroy not working as planned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a School model, and a Student model. On Student, I have `belongs_to :school, :dependent => destroy`.

However, upon deleting a school, the students whose ID is associated with that school are not deleted. In School, I also have `has_many :students`.

Is there any reason why this is not working? There is a `destroy` method in the Student model,  but it seems like nothing happens to the Student when its School is destroyed. Hoping someone can shed some light on this - perhaps I'm missing something major.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The :dependent option needs to be given for the has_many relationship in the school class...

```
class School
  has_many :students, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

You will also want to remove the destroy option on your belongs_to association, currently you will delete the associated school record when destroying a student...

```
class Student
  belongs_to :school
end
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, however when the school is destroyed, the students are fine. Is there something else I need to keep track of?

Comment: Well the above should work, so it might be something else, could you post the code in question so we can take a look?

Comment: Fixed, the reason was just the destroy method in Student. Thanks :)